# How to disable the submit button on a registration page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database

I am building a registration page for my website and i want to disable the submit button till all the fields have been validated using jQuery and AJAX (I found a way to do this at http://youhack.me/2010/05/04/username-availability-check-in-registration-form-using-jqueryphp/)... Now how do i use this to perform multiple checks and keep the submit button disabled until all the checks have passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would execute the validation code every time a user applies focus to an input, so use something like:

```
$('input').focus(function(){ /* Validation Code Here */ });
```

And then if it passes:

```
$('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled','false');
```

Comment: But this would enable the button when ANY ONE of the fields gets validated... I need to enable it only when ALL the fields are validated!

Comment: When I say 'validate' I mean you would validate the entire form each time.

Answer (score 1):

```
     var $submitButton = $(this, "input[type='submit']");
     $submitButton.attr("disabled", "true");
     validate();
     $submitButton.attr("disabled", "false");
```

however I think this was bugged in IE ..

Answer (score 0):

to disable

```
$('#submit_postcode').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

to re-enable

```
$('#submit_postcode').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Setting the attribute to any value causes it to be disabled, even .attr('disabled', 'false'), so it has to be removed